# Hide redirected from message when switching to another route

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am using react-router-dom redirect state to show redirected from the text on the login page if the user tries to access the protected route. It is working great but I am not able to disable it after refresh.
So when I refresh i should have no redirection text but there is still redirected from '/xyz'.

I have also tried switching between signup and then opening login again but it still shows redirected from '/xyz'.

Please share a solution to this.

Protected route code:-

```
import React from "react";
import { Redirect, Route } from "react-router-dom";


const ProtectedRoute = ({ component: Component,loggedIn ,...rest }) => {
  
  return ( <Route
      {...rest}
      render={(props) =>(
        loggedIn===true ? (
          <Component  {...props} />
        ) : (
          <Redirect
            to={{
              pathname: "/login",
              state: { from:props.location},
            }}
          />
        ))
      }
    />)
    };


export default ProtectedRoute;
```

Login Code

```
let {from}=props.location.state||{from:{pathname:'/home'},setFrom:()=>{}};

return {
  <>
   {from && <h1>Redirected from: {from.pathname}</h1>}
  </>
}
```

Routing:-

```
<Router>
  <Switch>
    <Route path='/login' exact  component={Login}/>
    <Route path='/signup' exact component={Signup}/>
    <ProtectedRoute path='/xyz' component={XYZ}/>
  </Switch>
</Router>
```